# React Navigation 5.0 Bottom Tab PreventDefault to disable tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to disable tab in my Bottom Tab Navigation. I have 2 code blocks but 1 will not disable the tab

Not Working. (Lockable.Navigation()) returns true or false promise

```
<Tab.Screen
      name="Profile"
      component={ProfileStackScreen}
      listeners={{
        tabPress: e => {
          // Prevent default action
          Lockable.Navigation().then(result => {
            console.log('the reso', result);
            if (result) {
              console.log(e);
            } else {
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          });
        },
      }}
```

Outputs: `{"defaultPrevented": false, "preventDefault": [Function value], "target": "Profile-RC9MTCtgFa1R8no6a8tNe", "type": "tabPress"}`

WORKS No Problem but I have no way to control it with my switch

```
<Tab.Screen
      name="Notifications"
      component={DetailsStackScreen}
      listeners={{
        tabPress: e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          // Prevent default action
        },
      }}
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault` needs to be called synchronously. You can't call it in a promise because it's asynchronous.

Whatever you `Lockable.Navigation()` is, instead of accessing it via a promise, you need to access it upfront (e.g. in `useEffect`, you probably also need to subscribe to changes here) and store it in your component's state.

Then you will be able to synchronously check it.